# How does operator [] of an address of variable work?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

for example:

```
int x = 5;
std::cout<<(&x)[0]<<std::endl; -> prints 5
```

i found this representation of 3DVector in one book:

```
struct Vector3D{
float x,y,z;
Vector3D() = default;
Vector3D(float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) {}
float & operator[](int i){
return ((&x)[i]);
}
};
```

and if use it as:

```
    Vector3D myVec(0,2,3);
    std::cout<<myVec[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<myVec[1]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<myVec[2]<<std::endl;
```

it will print values of x, y, z

How it works? And Is this safe?

Comment: why i'm must be sure that declared variables lie one by one? Or this works only in this particular case?

Comment: To have something safe, one must use [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). Also note "offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support", as it depends on member paddings of the structure

Comment: @ChrisMM *"they are stored that way in memory"* probably but not necessarily. It's not "normally considered unsafe". It's simply undefined behavior making it by definition always unsafe and never useful or helpful.

Comment: @ChrisMM i dont really understand. "and you will see problems... " is rather misleading. It is possible that no problems will be visible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `&x` you get a pointer to `x`.  When you do `pointer[N]` what the compiler does is translate that to `*(pointer + N)`.  In your code since `N` is `0` we are left with `*(&x)` which is just dereferencing the pointer we just created giving back the variable itself.

---

The code you found this in is actually undefined behavior.  When they do

```
float & operator[](int i){
    return ((&x)[i]);
}
```

They are assuming there is no padding in the class and treating the 3 separate members as if they were an array.  This assumption cannot be made though and the access is explicitly called out as undefined behavior from the standard.

Comment: More specifically, they are assuming that there is no padding between the members of the class. In fact, it is quite likely in practice that there is no padding between the members. But the behaviour is still undefined whether there is padding or not.

Comment: Note: practical consequences of this type of undefined behaviour (assuming there really is no padding) include *confusing the optimizer* so that your numbers don't actually get written anywhere, or so that it reads `x` instead of `y`, but only on certain compilers with certain options enabled.